# Gallery Albums issue

Tags: gallery

In android, the gallery app is showing albums from other locations which were not in gallery before. I have a folder on the internal storage which never showed up in gallery before, but now it does. Did I tell it to do that? no. So my question is: how do I hide this album so its just viewable as a folder from the file manager app. My version is 50.1. I fear that deleting the album will delete the folder.

Comment: Create an empty file called **.nomedia** and put it in that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hiding your files from the Media Scanner**

Include an empty file named `.nomedia` in your external files directory (*note the dot prefix in the filename*).

This prevents media scanner from reading your media files and providing them to other apps through the MediaStore content provider. However, if your files are truly private to your app, you should save them in an app-private directory.

[Source - Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)